# Functional equation on a ring

Tags: ring-theory, functional-equations

Let $R$ be a ring with identity. Find all functions $f: R \to \Bbb R$
satisfying the functional equation 
\begin{equation}
f(xp+yq, yp+xq)=f(x, y)f(p, q)
\end{equation}
for all $x, y, p, q\in R$, and 
\begin{equation}
f(x+y, x-y)=0
\end{equation}
for all $x, y\in R$. If $R$ is a field, or $f(2, 0)\ne 0$, then it can be shown that
$$
f(x, y)=M_1(x+y)M_2(x-y)
$$
for all $x, y\in R$, where $M_j(xy)=M_j(x)M_j(y)$ for all $x, y\in R$ and $j=1, 2$.

Comment: Do you mean "Find all functions $f:R\times R\to \mathbb{R}$ ..." in your second sentence?

Comment: Yes! I am sorry.

Comment: Dear @Chung, that's OK. What progress have you made on this question? Have you tried plugging in various values of $x,y,p,q$ in the functional equation and comparing to the equation $f(x+y,x-y)=0$?

Comment: Replacing $(x, y)$ by $(x+y, x-y)$, $(u, v)$ by $(u+v, u-v)$ we have $g(2xu, 2yv)=g(x, y)g(u, v)$ where $g(x, y)=f(x+y, x-y)$. Then we solve the equation for $g$ if $g(1,1)\ne 0$. We conclude that $g(x, y)=g(1,1)M_1(x)M_2(y)$. I want to know the case $g(1,1)=0$, equivalently, the case $g(x,y)=0$ for all $x, y\in R$.

Comment: Dear @Chung, I am not sure I understand your question. My understanding is that we are trying to determine all functions $f:R\times R \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the functional equation $f(xp+yq,yp+xq)=f(x,y)f(p,q)$ for all $x,y,p,q\in R$ **and** the functional equation $f(x+y,x-y)=0$ for all $x,y\in R$. In your comment above, you write that you can solve the equation if $g(x,y)=f(x+y,x-y)\neq 0$. But $f(x+y,x-y)=0$ for all $x,y\in R$ is one of the functional equations $f$ is supposed to satisfy. So, I am not sure why you considered the case $g(x,y)\neq 0$, because $g(x,y)=0$ by assumption ...

Comment: I mean, for the case $g\ne 0$, I solved it completely. It remain to solve the equation when $f(x+y, x-y)=0$ for all $x, y\in R$.